# SearchDelegate with ChangeNotifier + Provider

Tags: flutter

How to correctly use `ChangeNotifier` with `SearchDelegate`?

I have something that looks like this:

```dart
class SearchNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> results;


  Future<void> search(String query) async {
    results = await API.search(query);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And in my `SearchDelegate`:

```dart
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  final searchNotifier = Provider.of<SearchNotifier>(context);
  searchNotifier.search(query);
  ...
}
```

When the results update, `SearchNotifier` updates its listeners, `SearchDelegate` is rebuild, `buildSuggestions` is called and `search` is called again, entering in a loop.

Is there a way of doing `searchNotifier.search(query)` outside a build method? Maybe somehow I can add a listener to `SearchDelegate` `_queryTextController`?

I'm using provider to inject my `SearchNotifier`, so wherever call `search` we need to have access to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by returning the search results directly from the `search` method and then using a `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
class SearchNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<List<String>> search(String query) async {
    return await API.search(query);
  }
}

Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  final searchNotifier = Provider.of<SearchNotifier>(context);
  results = searchNotifier.search(query);
  // FutureBuilder on results
  ...
}
```

`SearchNotifier` does not need to be a `ChangeNotifier` anymore, since the origin of the issue was `notifyListeners`.

Answer (score 1):

I made it differently, but I am also using the Provider in my app. So my custom search delegate looks like this:

```
 class ExerciseSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // ExeciseList is a widget which accepts a query as optional parameter
    return ExerciseList(
      query: query,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Column();
  }

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme;
  }
}
```

and my ExerciseList looks like this:

```
class ExerciseList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String query;
  const ExerciseList({this.query, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _model = Provider.of<GlobalModel>(context);

    List<ExerciseModel> _results = query != null
        ? _model.exercises
            .where((ex) => ex.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
            .toList()
        : _model.exercises;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _results.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        var exercise = _results[position];
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(notifier: exercise),
          ],
          child: ExerciseListItem(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. If something is not clear, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: In this solution, does GlobalModel calls `notifyListeners` in any step? The problem that I had is that I would call `GlobalModel.search` inside `buildSuggestions`. `search` calls an external API and eventually call `notifyListeners`, causing `buildSuggestions` to be called again and the cycle would repeat.
After looking at your solution it gave me a hint on how to modify my code to fix the problem. I'm posting the solution here soon.

Comment: the showSearch is called when button is clicked, so even if widget is re-created because notifyListeners was called in some places the showSearch will not be called again, so buildSuggestions or buildResults will not be called twice. 

in my cases notifyListeners  is called inside the widget which I am using for the buildSuggestions and buildResults, and it just works.